# Using FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_NAME environment variable to set placeholder key/value pairs

Tags: flyway

[Documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/envvars#FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_) states that I can also use environment variables for Flyway configuration, instead of specifying them in Gradle files.

However, since placeholder are multivalued, how are these handled via environment variables?  Are they comma separated key value pairs?

```
"key1=val1,key2=val2"?
```

I cannot seem to find any such examples.

Answer (score 1):

*NAME* refers to the placeholder name.

To set the environment variable for placeholder `key1` use

`FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_KEY1=val1`